Cannot use Picker from @emoji-mart/react in typescript
I have the following React component for emoji picker in tsx. I am getting error and unable to resolve this.

JSX element type 'Picker' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
'Picker' cannot be used as a JSX component.


Its type 'typeof import("@emoji-mart/react", { with: { "resolution-mode": "import" } })' is not a valid JSX element type.ts(2786)

    import data from "@emoji-mart/data";
    import Picker from "@emoji-mart/react";
    import { SetStateAction, useState } from "react";
    import { FaRegSmile } from "react-icons/fa";
    import { useTheme } from "../../../Contexts/ThemeContext/ThemeContext.tsx";
    
    export default function EmojiPickerContainer() {
      const [emojiPickerDisplay, setEmojiPickerDisplay] = useState(false);
      const [currentEmoji, setCurrentEmoji] = useState(null);
      const { getTheme } = useTheme();
    
      const buttonClickHandler = () => {
        setEmojiPickerDisplay(true);
      };
    
      const emojiSelectHandler = (emoji: { native: SetStateAction<null> }) => {
        setCurrentEmoji(emoji.native);
        setEmojiPickerDisplay(false);
      };
    
      console.log(currentEmoji);
    
      return (
        <div className="relative inline-block">
          {!emojiPickerDisplay && (
            <button
              className="ml-2 p-2 text-2xl rounded border border-gray-500 bg-gray-100 dark:bg-zinc-600 text-black  hover:bg-gray-300  dark:text-white  focus:outline-none"
              onClick={buttonClickHandler}
            >
              <b>
                <FaRegSmile />
              </b>
            </button>
          )}
          {emojiPickerDisplay && (
            <div className="absolute bottom-full right-0 mb-2 z-50">
              <div className="overflow-y-auto  max-w-60 max-h-100 w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 scrollbar-thin">
                <Picker
                  data={data}
                  onEmojiSelect={emojiSelectHandler}
                  theme={getTheme() === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}
                  previewPosition="none"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }

I also created a type declaration with emoji-mart-react.d.ts
// src/types/emoji-mart-react.d.ts
declare module '@emoji-mart/react' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  interface PickerProps {
    data: any;
    onEmojiSelect: (emoji: any) => void;
    theme?: string;
    previewPosition?: string;
    // Add other props as needed
  }

  export const Picker: React.FC<PickerProps>;
}

Also added this in compilerOptions for tsconfig.json file
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],

Maybe you can try several things :

Add this gist to your project
Install @types/emoji-mart to your project's dependencies

I've tested an implementation in a NextJS project (tsx) with Emoji Mart :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zykald?file=app%2Fpage.tsx
Be careful, I've noticed that Emoji Mart only works in “use client” components, and not in those using “use server”.
